# Strange ListView scrolling issues

Tags: android, image, listview, background, scroll

I have a ListView in my app that has a background image. All of the rows are a semi transparent white (#35FFFFFF). Whenever I scroll the list, the rows turn a light green that obscures the background image until I stop scrolling (usually--sort of unpredictable). Sometimes it flickers between the background image/color and the green. And yes, I have set the cache color hint to #00000000. Any advice about this would be appreciated.

ListView xml:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="7px"        
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:dividerHeight="6px"
    android:"#75ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/list_bg"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    />
```

Row xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18px"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="#35ffffff"
    />
```

Bitmap xml:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/list_bg_bitmap"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    android:dither="true"
    />
```

Comment: I'm curious about the contents of list_bg.xml.

Comment: list_bg.xml is the Bitmap xml. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: I think that this is related to my problem ([Stackoverflow thread][1]) and might be a bug in Android.
Have you found a workaround yet?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055152/statelistdrawable-in-listview-strangely-off-colored-in-certain-conditions "Stackoverflow thread"

Comment: No, I haven't since I'm not working on this project anymore. But thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="7px"        
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:dividerHeight="6px"
    android:"#75ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/list_bg"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"

    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    />
```

Comment: Helped me a lot with:
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
Thanks!