# Setting background image of a ListItem created using ListAdapter for a while in Android

Tags: android, listview

I would like to set background image or a list item when selected or pressed and then back to normal state, just like a normal listview works.

I have created list using custom listadapter.

Cheers,
Prateek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [StateListDrawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) in Android for this.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055152/statelistdrawable-in-listview-strangely-off-colored-in-certain-conditions) includes some sample code.